# Have problem to rewritten UIKit to SwiftUI to create Star Animation

Tags: animation, swiftui, uikit, move

I want to created star animation to SwiftUI, but I write this code in UIKit to allow many many star without move star like that, just stuck on it. that is all.

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
    
    func createStar(view: UIView) {
        
        let starSize = 500
        
        for _ in 0...starSize {
            let xSpot = Int.random(in: 0...Int(view.frame.width))
            let ySpot = Int.random(in: 0...Int(view.frame.height))
            let sizeView = Int.random(in: 1...2)
            let colorView = Int.random(in: 1...3)
            let alphaStar = Double.random(in: 0.7...1.0)
            
            let stars = UIView()
            stars.frame = CGRect(x: xSpot, y: ySpot, width: sizeView, height: sizeView)
            stars.alpha = CGFloat(alphaStar)
            
            switch colorView {
            case 1: stars.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255, alpha: 1)
            case 2: stars.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
            case 3: stars.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
            default: break
            }
            
            stars.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(sizeView / 2)
            stars.accessibilityIdentifier = "Live Stars"
            view.addSubview(stars)
            view.sendSubviewToBack(stars)
        }
        starLiveWallpaper(view: view)
    }
    
    func starLiveWallpaper(view: UIView) {
        for x in view.subviews {
            if x.accessibilityIdentifier == "Live Stars" {
                let alphaStar = Double.random(in: 0.7...1.0)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
                    x.alpha = CGFloat(alphaStar)
                })
            }
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            self.starLiveWallpaper(view: view)
        })
    }
}
```

then put viewdidload()

```
 createStar(view: view)
```

Bingo! now start to talk about SwiftUI

Whenever I have tried  to studying about animation in SwiftUI and follow the same as UIKit to SwiftUI.

Here is SwiftUI.

```
struct StarView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<500) { _ in
                    Star(size: CGFloat.random(in: 1...2), color: Color.randomColor())
                        .position(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.width),
                                          y: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.height)))
                }
            }
            .accessibilityIdentifier("Live Stars")
        }
        .onAppear {
            starLiveWallpaper(view: UIApplication.shared.windows.first!)
        }
    }
    
    func starLiveWallpaper(view: UIView) {
        for x in view.subviews {
            if x.accessibilityIdentifier == "Live Stars" {
                let alphaStar = Double.random(in: 0.7...1.0)
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1)) {
                    x.alpha = CGFloat(alphaStar)
                }
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: {
            self.starLiveWallpaper(view: view)
        })
    }
}

struct Star {
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
    }
}

extension Color {
    static func randomColor() -> Color {
        let colors = [Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255),                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 255/255),                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255)]
        return colors.randomElement() ?? .white
    }
}



struct Star_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      //  ContentView()
        StarView()
    }
}
```

However, there is NO star on iPhone like what's goings. Over 3 days to research for nothings. More like this star animation on background. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: use `struct Star: View {...}`, increase the size to something like
 `Star(size: CGFloat.random(in: 5...10)`
 so we can see them. Works for me.

Comment: send me full code if you can then I can look up because I am new to SwiftUI.

Comment: Why rewrite? UIKit is much more efficient for animations

Comment: no I got someone swiftUI codes has solved our code whats I am look for. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some example code that makes your stars twinkle on the background.

Use `struct Star: View {...}`, increase the size of the stars
so we can see them. Use the adapted `BlinkViewModifier` from: [Button blink animation with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015929/button-blink-animation-with-swiftui)  as shown.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        StarView()
    }
}

struct StarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                ForEach(0..<500) { _ in
                    Star(size: CGFloat.random(in: 3...5),
                         color: Color.randomColor())
                    .position(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.width),
                                      y: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.height)))
                    .blinking(duration: Double.random(in: 0.6...1.0))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59015929/button-blink-animation-with-swiftui
struct BlinkViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    let duration: Double
    @State private var blinking: Bool = false
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .opacity(blinking ? 0 : Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0))
            .animation(.linear(duration: duration).repeatForever(), value: blinking)
            .onAppear {
                blinking = true
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func blinking(duration: Double = 0.5) -> some View {
        modifier(BlinkViewModifier(duration: duration))
    }
}

struct Star: View {
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color

    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
    }
}

extension Color {
    static func randomColor() -> Color {
        let colors = [Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255),                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 255/255),
                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255)]
        return colors.randomElement() ?? .white
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

You could also use this simple updated `struct Star: View {...}`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        StarView()
    }
}

struct StarView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Color.black.ignoresSafeArea()
                ForEach(0..<500) { _ in
                    Star(size: CGFloat.random(in: 3...5),
                         color: Color.randomColor())
                    .position(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.width),
                                      y: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.height)))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Star: View {
    @State private var blinking: Bool = false
    
    let size: CGFloat
    let color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(color)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .opacity(blinking ? 1 : Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0))
            .animation(.linear(duration: Double.random(in: 0.6...1.0)).repeatForever(), value: blinking)
            .onAppear {
                blinking = true
            }
    }
}

extension Color {
    static func randomColor() -> Color {
        let colors = [Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 200/255),                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 200/255, blue: 255/255),
                      Color(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255)]
        return colors.randomElement() ?? .white
    }
}
```

Comment: .position(CGPoint(x: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.width),
                                      y: CGFloat.random(in: 0...geometry.size.height))) this error say Value of type 'Star' has no member 'position'

Comment: updated my answer with `struct Star: View {...}`. This works very well for me.

Comment: updated my answer with a simpler approach, see EDIT-1

Comment: Prefect!!! However, that start at first is blackout then grow then 3 time shut and open shut open then at end is prefect but how can I remove at first animation like glow and pop as 3 time? Thanks!

Comment: if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it using the tick mark next to it, it turns green. Note with EDIT-1, I don't get 3 open/shut like you say.

Comment: ok, you could try using `.opacity(blinking ? 1 : Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0))` in `Star`, note `...blinking ? 1 ...` not `...blinking ? 0 ...` Seems to work better. I will update my answer.